# Keyboard event on windows

Tags: windows, qt, keyboard

I need to test keyboards keys so I created a virtual keyboard and light up keys when they are pressed>

On windows I get an issue, two key never send any signal : the print key & function key (located between the right alt gr and the right ctrl)

Also some key activate various signal when pressed (like turning on or off the sound...)

How can get a signal from these two keys with Qt ?

How can I override windows control over the keyboard during the test so that I will be the only one to receive keyboard input ?

Comment: For this you'd probably be much better off to simply hook up the keyboard to a low-cost USB analyzer, and script the test on top of this.

Comment: Ok, but what about laptops ? Also, I have a lot of other tests I didn't mention (network, sound, screen, hdd....)

Comment: No idea. You're also assuming that the keyboard sends the keycodes when you depress the keys. The keyboard controller might be processing those keystrokes directly. Perhaps you want to test if the combination of `Fn` and other keys works as desired, and the combination of `Ctrl+PrtScr`.

Comment: no, I'm working with the native scan code, which doesn't depend of what key aasociation you are using (like ctrl or fn or alt...). if you press two key, you got two input, one for each key.

Comment: You're still assuming that these can't be synthesized. I've just tried with a USB keyboard from the inside of a laptop computer I had laying around. Yes, the built-in keyboard+trackpad are a USB device. Pressing Fn itself generates no interrupts on that particular keyboard, but pressing Fn+key generates different key code than pressing the key alone. This is just a single anecdote, it doesn't mean that this behavior is widespread - just that you shouldn't be surprised by it if you happen to run into it. It also doesn't imply that the keyboard can't be reconfigured not to be quiet about Fn.